# resize and compress image on upload from gallery

Tags: android

i want compress image on upload from gallery.
i use "id.zelory:compressor" library for this purpose.

```
            case REQUEST_GALLERY_CODE: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                try {
                    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                    String type = getFileExtension(data.getData());
                    UploadImage(getBytes(inputStream) , type);
```

and getbytes function :

```
    private byte[] getBytes(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuff = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int buffSize = 1024;
    byte[] buff = new byte[buffSize];
    int len = 0;
    while ((len = is.read(buff)) != -1) {
        byteBuff.write(buff, 0, len);
    }
    return byteBuff.toByteArray();
}
```

i want before send image to upload (UploadImage()) compress it by using this :

```
compressedImageFile = new Compressor(this).compressToFile(actualImageFile);
```

but input this code is actualImageFile!
how can do this?

Comment: so,when i upload an image that its size is for example 3M ,in the server the size of image is 3M.i want reduce image size .

Comment: Do you already have your actual size image available? I'm not understanding this line "but input this code is actualImageFile! how can do this?"

Answer (score 0):

You can use native quality change. In my latest project I have used smth like this:

```
 val image = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
 val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
 image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,IMAGE_QUALITY, byteArrayOutputStream)
 val byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
 service.send(Item(Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT))
```

IMAGE_QUALITY is a number from 0-100. You can play with a number to see what quality will satisfy your needs

Comment: thanks ,but i want use "id.zelory:compressor" library that is better.